# substring_index using in mysql

Tags: mysql

In MY table  column contains (string,string2,string3),string many vary from row to row, one row contain 2 and other row contain 3.
I have to insert these column in another table contains 2 columns ,i have to kept 1 string before delimter in one column  in 1 column and reaming In another column

Comment: No problem ,i get that asnwer from ryan,thanks for all who try to answer my question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes that the 'source' column always has at least one comma(',') in it then this should do what you require. It has been tested on a different table.

```
SELECT  `source`,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(`source`, ',', 1) AS firstField,  
        SUBSTRING(`source`, LOCATE(',', `source`) + 1) AS restOfField 
FROM `data_table`
```

Comment: HI,Ryan Vincent Thanks for the answer,  its really Helps me a lots